# Java sound frequency synthesizing

Tags: java, audio, synthesize

I'm trying to build a frequency generator in java, but i'm having some trouble. For some reason I'm getting exactly what I want on my headphone speaker, but when I try the same code on my macbook pro 13" speaker it just doesn't work. The problem only occurs for **high** frequencies (i'm trying between 19kHz to 20kHz). For **lower** frequencies (such as 10kHz) I get the right results.

I'm using a sample rate of 44100.

Here is the code to play the produced sine frequency:

```
AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, true );
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info ( SourceDataLine.class, af );
SourceDataLine source = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine( info );
source.open(af);
source.start();

source.write( buf, 0, buf.length );
source.drain();
source.stop();
source.close();
```

Here is how I'm generating the buffer:

```
    public void play(float seconds, int sampleRate, double frequency){

        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
            sample[i] = Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/frequency)));
        }
        for (final double dVal : sample) {
            final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));                

            buf[pos++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
            buf[pos++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);

        }
    }
```

[UPDATE]

The problem starts at 18kHz. 
Right now the best explanation is:

> It's possible there's some fairly agressive anti-aliasing filters in
>   the mac, and that the dog park software app isn't using PCM buffering
>   to generate the sounds, like you are. I would try a higher sampling
>   frequency if possible.
>   Blockquote -(comment made by Robert)
>   But we are not 100% sure if this is precise.

One alternative solution is to plug an external speaker (make sure the computer volume is set to maximum, and regulate it on the speaker).

Comment: I'm old enough now where I can't hear sound above about 16kHz.  Are you sure you are capable of hearing those tones, or your headphones/speakers are capable of reproducing them?  I'm pretty sure the mac built-in speaker won't produce a 19kHz tone.  Try setting your macbook in front of your dog, and see what happens.

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I'm using this: http://dogparksoftware.com/iSpectrum.html to observe the frequencies, and I'm also sure that that speakers are capable of playing this frequencies because I was able to play then using this: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/29891/tonegen

Comment: OK.  So at what frequency does the sound stop?

Comment: That's pretty close to the Nyquist frequency.  It's possible there's some fairly agressive anti-aliasing filters in the mac, and that the dog park software app isn't using PCM buffering to generate the sounds, like you are.  I would try a higher sampling frequency if possible.  What is the application for this?

Comment: That makes sense. I've already tried higher frequencies sampling, and had no luck with that. I'm doing a college project that requires this. I'll try to play it on external speakers instead of headphones. I'll let you know if this works.

Comment: Ok, I got some mysterious results again. I'm using really good speakers (and loud), The only way I can get clear results on low frequencies is if turn volume up quite a bit (wich is not very considerative to dogs)

Comment: You mean high frequencies don't you?  You're reaching the limit of your own hearing.

Comment: Oh sure, sorry. high frequencies.

Comment: ok, couple more tests. I'm using aux cable to send the audio to the speaker, and I had my macbook volume about half way through, because of that I was probably sending low quality sound to the speakers and therefore not geting good results. Now that I have than all the way up, It's working better. Thank you very much for that!

Comment: You say "The problem is only occurs for low frequencies (i'm trying between 19kHz to 20kHz). For lower frequencies (such as 10kHz) I get the right results." 10kHz would not usually be considered a "lower frequency", but it is lower than 19kHz-20kHz. Also there's been a lot of discussion. Can you update/correct your post, then maybe we can be more helpful.

Comment: Look, your laptop speakers have pretty tight limits on the ranges they can reproduce, and that software you're using to test your theories is  probably sampling the sound card's output directly.  Also, it's hard to get clear signals as you approach the Nyquist frequency, as Robert pointed out.  This has nothing to do with software.  If you need a signal generator for some project that requires quality high frequencies, either get a sound card that samples at 96kHz, or build a proper analog tone generator.

Comment: @Brad thank's for that. But what still bothering me is that if the other software can do why wouldn't I be able to do it too? Do you know how can I develop a "sampling the sound card's output directly" program?

Comment: @Filipe, Other software **can't** do that.  This isn't a software problem, the problem is that your speakers cannot output those frequencies.  What I'm telling you is that your test methods are flawed.